# How to get the pk parameter in return redirect

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view:

```
@login_required
def add_auditor(request, pk, pk2):
    company_details = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=pk)
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk2)

    company_details.auditor.add(user_profile.name)
    company_details.save()

    return redirect(reverse('company:search_auditors' , pk=company_details.pk))
```

The redirect url in this view is not working as it has a primary key parameter in it.

When I try to add_auditor or run the view it is throughing me this error:

```
TypeError: reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

How to pass a primary key parameter in redirect url?

Any idea

Comment: What you mean by *not working*?

Comment: It is not redirecting to the desired location rather giving me this error `reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the kwargs in reverse() function by following syntax:

`return redirect(reverse('company:search_auditors' , kwargs={'pk':company_details.pk}))`

[more details on reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/)

Answer (score 2):

The data should be passed through the **`kwargs`** argument as below,

```
return redirect(reverse('company:search_auditors', kwargs={"pk": company_details.pk}))
```

**Ref : [Django `reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)**